# C++ return char array without using buffer

Tags: c++, arrays

I wanted to implement a function with signature like this:
`char* func(int a, int b)`

I know a more common way to do this would be also passing a `char*` as one of the parameters and return that, but that is not an option for this implementation.

I would use malloc or a new operator inside the function, but I need to release the allocated memory to preventing leaking after the function returned. And I think that is a bad practice.

```
char* func(int a, int b) {
    char* arr = new char[];
    return arr;
}
// need to free the space in main
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Update:

Yes I finally decided to use `static char arr[20]` like this. I was worried about many things but can someone tell me whether doing so will cause any potential buffer overflow. You know, if I accidentally access and overwrite it with more space. It is stored in global/static area, not stack or heap, so I'm not sure.

Comment: idk why, but all I could think of is: what exactly does int a and int b do in this function lol

Comment: Why not `std::string func(int a, int b)` or `std::vector<char> func(int a, int b)` ?

Comment: There are many better ways, but none that don't change the function prototype. If this is an assignment from a programming text or course, the lesson you are probably expected to learn is "Don't do this."

Comment: One tempting approach that does not change the prototype is to declare a `static` array that you can return without it going out of scope, but that results in a non-reentrant function and worse, a function that you can't call again until any caller is no longer using the returned buffer. Pain in the neck tracking that, so I'd typically rank it as an as-bad-or-worse option than `new`.

Comment: Use a `std::unique_ptr<char[],CustomDeleter>` would be an option, if you don't want to go with vector/string. A type wrapping array and size would be preferrable though...

Comment: "I would use malloc or a new operator inside the function, but I need to release the allocated memory to preventing leaking after the function returned. And I think that is a bad practice." you have just described why std::string is what you should be returning

Comment: Yes I finally decided to use ```static char arr[20]``` like this. I was worried about many things but can someone tell me whether doing so will cause any potential buffer overflow. You know, if I accidentally access and overwrite it with more space. It is stored in global/static area, not stack or heap, so I'm not sure.

Comment: BTW, it is _not_ “bad practice” to require the user to free a block of memory you return — it is in fact _common_ practice — but since you are using C++ why not just return a `std::string`? Why force the `char *` thing?

Comment: As @Dúthomhas said: Not bad practice at all -- but a rather typical C and "old school" C++ idiom. The key is clear communication to the users, by documenting it. Memory management without containers and smart pointers is a frequent source of errors and a royal pain in the behind to get right. But for 10 years now, with the introduction of move semantics in C++, you can simply return containers by value without large penalties, obviating the need to manually manage memory.

Comment: It is not bad practice when allocation and free happened in the same scope. In this case the array gets allocated memory inside the function but needs to be freed outside. I think it'll become too much to keep track of.

Answer (score 2):

If you must have an array of `char`, then you can use `std::vector<char> charVec;` Then, if you are using an API function that requires a `char*`, you can use `charVec.data()` to get the raw pointer (just don't `delete` it, or anything like that).

Otherwise, `std::string` is your easiest bet. You can also get the raw `char*` from a string instance, for example `std::string s; s.c_str();`

Comment: Note that `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*` , so if you need a `char*` then use `std::string::data()` instead in C++17 and later, or `&s[0]` prior to C++17.